# restarting of Ubuntu 14.04 installation using virtual box

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, virtualbox

I am installing Ubuntu 14.04 on the virtual box, and after the installation completes, it says that the computer needs to be restarted to complete the installation. There is a restart now button beneath that and when I click on it, a error message appears that "`oracle virtual box has stopped working`". When I again open the machine through virtual box, it again asks for installation. Why is this happening?

I am using version 4.3.8 r92456 Virtual box and my host system is windows 8.

Also, when I open Ubuntu for installation, there is an option of trying Ubuntu without installing it. I clicked on that to use Ubuntu, and it was extremely slow on virtual box. This has happened earlier as well when I installed a previous version of Ubuntu, it was extremely slow and was lagging. I have enabled the 3D acceleration from settings, but I guess it doesn't help. What might be wrong?

Comment: What version of Virtualbox are you using, and what is the host system?

Comment: @Wilf, updated.

Comment: @bjohn It might help to try a newer version of VirtualBox

Comment: Alright. I will try that as well.

Comment: Nothing has helped.

Answer (score 1):

detach the ubuntu ISO file / DVD drive from virtualbox and restart it. this should suffice to get you back to ubuntu you have already installed.

Answer (score -1):

First change the boot device order in BIOS ,Then try

Comment: Sorry but do you mean enabling acceleration through BIOS?

Comment: Press F12 while booting. and change the order..

Comment: Just randomly change the order to anything?

Comment: No use hard disk...

Comment: Please click edit below your answer and add what boot order you are suggesting.